# Excel equivalent for R dplyr group by command

Tags: r, excel, dplyr, filter

I'm trying to find an **excel filter equivalent** for the R code attached below.

I have a dataset with multiple rows with some data for a given ID (i.e. there may be more than one row per ID). What I want to do is drop rows based on whether the minimum status identifier is equal to 0.

e.g. For ID 2 both status values are equal to 1, hence it is in Phase 2 and all rows with ID 2 should be dropped.

Here a reproducable code sample in R:

```
library(dplyr)

n = 10

set.seed(1)
ID <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3)
Status <- sample(c(0,1), n, replace = TRUE)
Data <- as.data.frame(cbind(ID, Status))

Data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Test = if_else(min(Status) == 0, "Phase 1", "Phase 2"))
```

Comment: "For ID 2 both status values are equal to 1" it is not valid, I think you mean ID 3

Answer (score 2):

With ID in column A and Status in B, I can put this in C2 and fill down to get the same output. The logic is that it's finding the `min` Status value for all the cells whose ID matches the current one. Then we add 1 and paste on "Phase " at the start.

```
="Phase "&1+MINIFS($B$2:$B$11,$A$2:$A$11,A2)
```

Then you could filter out the `Test` values using Data->Filter. I don't think there is a formula command in Excel that will do that for you (without getting into overcomplicated VBA macros).